How to hide custom tab bar on specific stack/ screen in nested navigation?
My nav structure looks like this
App.js
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Auth">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Auth"
          component={AuthLayout}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Tabs"
          component={Tabs}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>

Tabs.js
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}
      initialRouteName="Main"
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        headerShown: false,
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={HomeLayout}
        options={{ title: "My home"}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileLayout}
        options={{ title: "Profile"}}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>

HomeLayout.js
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => (
            <Header
              navigation={navigation}
              route={route}
              options={options}
              back={back}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen A"
        component={ScreenA}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => (
            <Header
              navigation={navigation}
              route={route}
              options={options}
              back={back}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen B"
        component={ScreenB}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => (
            <Header
              navigation={navigation}
              route={route}
              options={options}
              back={back}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>

My goal is to hide tab bar on Screen A, Screen B, and some other screens.
I searched for the solution and also tried implementing tabBarVisible, but I had no luck in my case, the custom tab bar still there. So, how can I hide it for the specific screen only? Why doesn't tabBarVisible work?

So you kind of put yourself in the corner here. Because of the way you structured your screens, it might be pretty challenging to do what you need to do. What I can suggest for you is:
Issue with your approach: Because you are nesting
stack screens under a tab navigator, stack screens will always reside under the tab navigator. When I attempted to manually hide/show the tab bar, as you are trying to do, I encountered a performance issue even on the latest phones. I highly suggest you change your structure and nest your tab screens under a stack navigator first.
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Auth">
<Stack.Screen
  name="Auth"
  component={AuthLayout}
  options={{ headerShown: false }}
/>
<Stack.Screen
  name="HomeStack"
  component={HomeStacks} // HomeLayout.tsx
  options={{ headerShown: false }}
/>
</Stack.Navigator>

<Tab.Navigator
tabBar={(props) => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}
initialRouteName="Main"
screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
  headerShown: false,
})}
>
<Tab.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={Home} // Home screen component
  options={{ title: "My home"}}
/>
<Tab.Screen
  name="Profile"
  component={ProfileLayout}
  options={{ title: "Profile"}}
/>
</Tab.Navigator>

<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Tabs"
        component={Tabs} // Tabs.tsx
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => (
            <Header
              navigation={navigation}
              route={route}
              options={options}
              back={back}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen A"
        component={ScreenA}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => (
            <Header
              navigation={navigation}
              route={route}
              options={options}
              back={back}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen B"
        component={ScreenB}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => (
            <Header
              navigation={navigation}
              route={route}
              options={options}
              back={back}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>

